# Custom AddOn, Using SimplePie to display an enclosure

Tags: add-on-development, rss

I need to display an RSS feed on my site. I could use the built in RSS_Parser add-on, however that add-on does not appear to support adding an item enclosure (image). This is a requirement for this project.

I have elected to write my own. I have loaded the SimplePie library and I have it essentially working, just like the native Add-On, but the enclosure is not working.

I'm trying to put all the attributes into an array, like so:

```
        $items[] = array(
            'item_title'        => $item->get_title(),
            'item_link'         => $item->get_permalink(),
            'item_date'         => $item->get_date('U'),
            'item_content'      => $item->get_content(),
            'item_img'          =>  $item->get_enclosure(),
            'item_description'  => $item->get_description(),
            'item_categories'   => $categories,
            'item_authors'      => $authors
        );
    }
    return $items;
```

However, when using the item_img tag in the template, it returns a string of gibberish. Anyone know how to get it to return the url to the enclosure?

The feed i'm trying to parse is here: http://tntoday.utk.edu/feed/

I have done this with straight-up PHP, but having it as an add-on, easily accessible to content editors throughout the site would be greatly preferred.

Comment: Note: No code tags supported in comments, so I'll make it an answer after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Basically the error was being cause when an entry did not have an enclosure. The answer was to check if it *had* an enclosure first.

So it goes something like this:

```
if ( $enclosure = $item->get_enclosure() ) {   // If there is an image. 
        $items[] = array(
                'item_title'            => $item->get_title(),
                'item_link'             => $item->get_permalink(),
                'item_date'             => $item->get_date('U'),
                'item_content'        => $item->get_content(),
                'item_description'  => $item->get_description(),
                'item_categories'   => $categories,
                'item_authors'      => $authors,
                'item_img'          =>  $item->get_enclosure(0)->get_link()
        );
  } else {   // if there is not

            $items[] = array(
                'item_title'            => $item->get_title(),
                'item_link'             => $item->get_permalink(),
                'item_date'             => $item->get_date('U'),
                'item_content'        => $item->get_content(),
                'item_description'  => $item->get_description(),
                'item_categories'   => $categories,
                'item_authors'      => $authors,
                'item_img'      => '/images/interface/no-thumb.jpg'
            );
    }
  return $items;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple test like

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('http://tntoday.utk.edu/feed/');
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item)
{
    if ($enclosure = $item->get_enclosure())
    {
        echo $enclosure->embed();
    }
}
```

What do you get?

Comment: To make it work I had to make some modifications...
`
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('http://tntoday.utk.edu/feed/');
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();
ob_start();
    $this->return_data = "<h3>Hello World</h3>";
    foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item)
    {
        if ($enclosure = $item->get_enclosure())
        {
            echo $enclosure->get_link();
        }
    }
`
HOWEVER, the tag in the Template will return the "hello world"... but the simple pie stuff appears at the Beginning of the page (regardless) of the tag.

Comment: any thoughts on this?